# Return all methods in a COM object

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to write a simple script that will list all methods of a COM object. 
`New-Object -com Application.Name | Format-Custom * -Depth 4` doesn't work as the methods are not returned. I know I could do a ForEach loop on every name returned, however I don't want to end up with 20 ForEach loops. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this:

```
(New-Object -COMObject Application.Name) | Get-Member -MemberType Method
```

Comment: This only lists the immediate methods to the object, I'm looking for the methods of any properties as well as any other methods contained in those methods.